# Android : Dynamically Initialize Integer Array : Material Dialog Library

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, integer

```
Integer[] selsected;
selected = new Integer[] {1,2};
```

This makes an integer array with fixed size of two.

But I need a an `Integer[]` array with dynamic size. Some times with 3 items or more…

Because I am using [MaterialDialog multichoice list dialog](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs#multi-choice-list-dialogs) and it uses `Integer[]` to show already selected items.

If I use above selected array, it shows `1,2` as selected always and if user selected `2` and `3` I want to show these positions as selected when user choose dialog again. Is there any way?

Code:

```
Integer[] selsected;
selected = new Integer[] {1,2};
new MaterialDialog.Builder(this).title(R.string.socialNetworks)
    .items(socialNetworks)
    .itemsCallbackMultiChoice(selected, (dialog, which, text) -> {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < which.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) str.append('\n');
            str.append(which[i]);
            str.append(": ");
            str.append(text[i]);
        }
        showToast(str.toString());
        return true; // allow selection
    })
    .onNeutral((dialog, which) -> dialog.clearSelectedIndices())
    .onPositive((dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
    .alwaysCallMultiChoiceCallback()
    .positiveText(R.string.md_choose_label)
    .autoDismiss(false)
    .neutralText(R.string.clear_selection)
    .show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array list and integer array

initialize

```
List<Integer> myin=new ArrayList<>(); //you can add to this dynamically

myin.add(1); //adding values

myin.add(2);

Integer [] selected = myin.toArray(new Integer[myin.size()]); //converting to array
```

ArrayList is used for dynamically adding of values other than ordinary arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Initilize your `Integer[]` as:

```
Integer[] selected = new Integer[socalNetowrks.length];
```